# Kohana has_many relationship

Tags: php, orm, kohana, relationship

I'm using kohana 3.2 and I need help with has_many relationship. The table is written empty data...

So, my `User_education` model look like: http://gyazo.com/218139e52d85718c0d47bb802f0856fe  `User_personal` model : http://gyazo.com/49fd4ab4fb7506cf8b7c608733a70365
and controller: http://gyazo.com/7d13dd3901870d7ad3d62c09e90a9c14 but fields in database still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the foreign key in your models:

```
class Model_User_Personal extends ORM 
{
        protected $_has_many = array(
                    'educations' => array(
                        'model' => 'user_education',
                        'foreign_key' => 'user_personal_id',
                    ),
        );
}
```

The same foreign key should be set in `Model_User_Education`:

```
class Model_User_Education extends ORM 
{
        protected $_belongs_to = array(
                    'user_personal' => array(
                        'model' => 'user_personal',
                        'foreign_key' => 'user_personal_id',
                    ),
        );
}
```

Comment: So, my User_education model look like: http://gyazo.com/218139e52d85718c0d47bb802f0856fe User_personal model : http://gyazo.com/49fd4ab4fb7506cf8b7c608733a70365 and controller: http://gyazo.com/7d13dd3901870d7ad3d62c09e90a9c14 but fields in database still empty